# Building WebRTC for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, webrtc

I am trying to get started with WebRTC for Android.

I found couple of solutions on doing this with older version of WebRTC. Now the libjingle API is part of WebRTC.

I looked into http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started Can any one please point me to a resource which explains the steps?

Thanks.

Comment: all the steps are there in the link. Just install the prerequisite software given in the link.